# Access select Query

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access, gridview

I'm trying to import data from an Access Database to a Datatable, that I want to show in a gridview.

I'm using two textboxes, one with the starting value and the second with the ending value. As I enter values in the textboxes it shows the gridview filling with the data. That works, but my problem is the gridview is showing me data from the whole Access Table and not only the data between the strating and ending values that I want.

```
protected DataTable DataLoad()
{
    string queryString = "SELECT  SNR,.... ,......,......,.......,......  FROM Mytable Where SNR Between '" + tb_SNRFrom.Text + "'And '" + tb_SNRTil.Text + "'";
    {
        try
        {
          OleDbCommand command1 = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection);
          OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command1);
          DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
          da.Fill(dataset);
          table = dataset.Tables[0];
        }
        catch (OleDbException exp)
        {
            Response.Write("Database Error:" + exp.Message.ToString());
        }
        connection.Close();

        return table;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: @Soner is right about using parameter. they may even solve your date range problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using `SELECT  SNR,.... ,......,......,.......,......  FROM Mytable Where SNR >= @SmallValue And SNR <= @LargeValue;` when you know your upper & lower limit..

Comment: well the Programm is a search mask. I cant fix the lower and upper -  Limit once for always.

Comment: largevalue and smallvalue are not fixed values. they are parametes to be passed from both text boxes. and what I mean to say from lower and upper limit is that you have one textbox for upper limit and one for lower limit

Comment: What is the datatype of SNR? Also try executing the absolute value query in the Access and check if the returned data is filtered or not.

Comment: And what kind of data is there in the column? provide some examples.

Comment: For instance i ve put in the text boxes the values: 197, 222 and i got snr=197................................2154! 2154 is the end SRN of the Table

Comment: You have to change the datatype of SRN from text to int or any numeric type then only the filtering will work